# Telling spring IOC not to create a bean during startup of application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

During the startup phase spring would create a bean for the below component.

```
@Component
public class FeedKafkaConsumer {}
```

Is there a way to tell spring via JVM parameters or application.yml to NOT create the bean with name '`FeedKafkaConsumer`'. We can surely do this via `@ConditionalOnProperty` however that would require re-deployment of the code.

Comment: Any changes in JVM parameters or application.yml will require restart/redeployment as well

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko definitely it would. however, may be if spring has this feature out of the box, i could do a rolling restart without any code changes/ patch releases.

Comment: Why do you want to not create this bean on startup? Do you want to create it later (lazily)? Or do you not want to create this bean ever?

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen lets consider a case where i have a spring application deployed as client-server(server holds a distributed-cache). i have 3 nodes of client and 2 nodes of server. Now, the consumers would only be enabled on 3 nodes of client and would not run on 2 nodes of server. By this i would be able to consume CPU of my clients and keep my servers CPU light.